# drawing same image too much change image

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        canvas {
           width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
    <button onclick="drawMask()" >click</button>
    <script src="./index.js"  ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

/index.js

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";
const mask = new Image();

mask.onload = function () {
    canvas.width = mask.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = mask.naturalHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0);
}
mask.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/61qpVnB/test.png';

function drawMask() {
    // I try with ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy' it works but i need ->
    // -> ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; to merge with existing canvas content
    ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0);
}
```

there is a link https://jsfiddle.net/mikayelabrahamyan/e42bdozv/17/ plaice click to button to see how change the image.

I try with ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy' it works but i need to merge with existing canvas content using **source-over** (default globalCompositeOperation)

**How avoid image  mutation ??**

Comment: Your image has some transparency.  Try `mask.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/rNY6mAU.jpg';` (a different image with no transparency).  BTW `source-over` does not merge with canvas content.  It simply renders on top of the canvas.  I'm not sure if I understand what you want.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation for docs on the drawing operations.

Comment: I know that my image has some transparency. Question about this case. With transparency images

Comment: Well look through the options in the link I provided.  I think `source-atop` may be what you want.

Comment: source-atop not help me because when i erase some part of existing context it give me wrong result

Comment: You might have to use two images: The first is a stencil with no opacity, but the same shape.  Use destination-out to cut out a hole in the background.  Then draw in the image you want.